# Why React re-rendering performs better using INDEX AS KEY PROP in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I'm doing some experiments to observe the performance disparity in React re-rendering between using array indices as key props and using unique values as key props. Surprisingly, using index as the key outperforms using values as keys. Here's my testing approach: displaying a list of numbers from 0 to 9999 initially, then adding new numbers to the beginning of the array when the button is clicked.

##### Index as key:

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-framework-khk243?file=/src/App.js

```
export default App = () => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState(_.range(10000));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setArr([arr[0] - 1, ...arr])}>unshift</button>
      <ul>
        {arr.map((k, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{k}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: GIF showing results of index as key experiment]

##### Unique value as key:

https://codesandbox.io/s/old-cherry-9tjffv?file=/src/App.jsx

```
export default App = () => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState(_.range(10000));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setArr([arr[0] - 1, ...arr])}>unshift</button>
      <ul>
        {arr.map((k, i) => (
          <li key={k}>{k}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this scenario, the view refreshes after a few seconds when the button is clicked repeatedly, worse than that keyed by indices, truly surprising!!

[image: GIF showing results of unique value as key experiment]

---

To the best of my understanding, with unique value as the key, during the diffing phase, React identifies that the only difference lies in the first element, while the others remain unchanged. As a result, the only operation applied on the real DOM tree is the insertion of the new `<li>` element.

In the case of using the index as the key, updates are required for all 10,000 elements with shifted values, necessitating a total of 10,000 operations, plus one insertion of the new `<li>` element. **I suppose this approach is significantly slower than the alternative, but it doesn't appear to be the case.**

Any idea what leads to the noticeable delay?

Comment: Updated the first link. In the scenario where unique values are used as keys, the view refreshes after a few seconds when the button is clicked repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

## A performance test

### Method

I wrote a performance test utilising the [`Profiler`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Profiler) component. This component wraps the list and measures two things:

- The number of milliseconds spent rendering itself and its descendants for the current update. React calls this the `actualDuration`.
- The number of milliseconds estimating how much time it would take to re-render itself and its entire subtree without any optimisations. React calls this the `baseDuration`.

The test is run by programmatically clicking the <kbd>unshift</kbd> buttons in each case 500 times.

You can run the test yourself – it's included in a Stack Snippet under the next **Demo** heading. Results are logged in the console. For me, it takes a little over 1 minute for the test to run to completion.

> #### ℹ️ Note
>
> - The test case for using the array indices as the key is named **`unstable-key`**.
> - The test case for using the array values as the key is named **`stable-key`**.

### Results

I consistently found the case for `stable-key` faster than `unstable-key` which is inline with expectations set by React's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children). A sample of results for the `actualDuration` is below:

|  | unstable-key (ms) | stable-key (ms) | diff (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mean | 26.45 | 22.08 | -16.52 |
| median | 26 | 22 | -15.38 |
| mode | 27 | 22 | -18.52 |
| max | 54 | 35 | -35.19 |
| min | 18 | 15 | -16.67 |

The mean, median and mode are very close together which suggests very consistent timings.

I haven't included the results for `baseDuration` here because we're not running any optimisations (like memoisation) so I don't think they're relevant. However, it is noteworthy that they had unexpected results in that all the numbers were lower than `actualDuration`.

### Demo

```js
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { Profiler, StrictMode, useState } = React;

const unstableKeyPerfRecords = [];
const stableKeyPerfRecords = [];

const Test = ({ name }) => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState(Array.from({ length: 10000 }).map((_, index) => index));

  const onProfilerRender =
    (id, phase, actualDuration, baseDuration, startTime, commitTime) =>
      (name === "unstable-key" ? unstableKeyPerfRecords : stableKeyPerfRecords).push({
        id,
        phase,
        actualDuration,
        baseDuration,
        startTime,
        commitTime,
      });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setArr([arr[0] - 1, ...arr])}>unshift</button> 
      <Profiler id={name} onRender={onProfilerRender}>
        <ul>
          {arr.map((k, i) => (
            <li key={name === "unstable-key" ? i : k}>{k}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </Profiler>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => (
  <div id="wrapper">
    <Test name="unstable-key" />
    <Test name="stable-key" />
  </div>
);


const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);

function perfTest() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((button) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        button.click();
      }, 0);
    });
  }
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log({ unstableKeyPerfRecords });
    console.log({ stableKeyPerfRecords });

    console.log({
      actualDuration: {
        max: {
          unstableKey: _.maxBy(unstableKeyPerfRecords, ({ actualDuration }) => actualDuration).actualDuration,
          stableKey: _.maxBy(stableKeyPerfRecords, ({ actualDuration }) => actualDuration).actualDuration,
        },
        min: {
          unstableKey: _.minBy(unstableKeyPerfRecords, ({ actualDuration }) => actualDuration).actualDuration,
          stableKey: _.minBy(stableKeyPerfRecords, ({ actualDuration }) => actualDuration).actualDuration,
        },
        mean: {
          unstableKey: _.meanBy(unstableKeyPerfRecords, ({ actualDuration }) => actualDuration),
          stableKey: _.meanBy(stableKeyPerfRecords, ({ actualDuration }) => actualDuration),
        },
        median: {
          unstableKey: math.median(_.map(unstableKeyPerfRecords, ({ actualDuration }) => actualDuration)),
          stableKey: math.median(_.map(stableKeyPerfRecords, ({ actualDuration }) => actualDuration)),
        },
        mode: {
          unstableKey: math.mode(_.map(unstableKeyPerfRecords, ({ actualDuration }) => actualDuration)),
          stableKey: math.mode(_.map(stableKeyPerfRecords, ({ actualDuration }) => actualDuration)),
        },
      },
      baseDuration: {
        max: {
          unstableKey: _.maxBy(unstableKeyPerfRecords, ({ baseDuration }) => baseDuration).baseDuration,
          stableKey: _.maxBy(stableKeyPerfRecords, ({ baseDuration }) => baseDuration).baseDuration,
        },
        min: {
          unstableKey: _.minBy(unstableKeyPerfRecords, ({ baseDuration }) => baseDuration).baseDuration,
          stableKey: _.minBy(stableKeyPerfRecords, ({ baseDuration }) => baseDuration).baseDuration,
        },
        mean: {
          unstableKey: _.meanBy(unstableKeyPerfRecords, ({ baseDuration }) => baseDuration),
          stableKey: _.meanBy(stableKeyPerfRecords, ({ baseDuration }) => baseDuration),
        },
        median: {
          unstableKey: math.median(_.map(unstableKeyPerfRecords, ({ baseDuration }) => baseDuration)),
          stableKey: math.median(_.map(stableKeyPerfRecords, ({ baseDuration }) => baseDuration)),
        },
        mode: {
          unstableKey: math.mode(_.map(unstableKeyPerfRecords, ({ baseDuration }) => baseDuration)),
          stableKey: math.mode(_.map(stableKeyPerfRecords, ({ baseDuration }) => baseDuration)),
        },
      },
    });
  }, 0);
}

setTimeout(perfTest, 0);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#wrapper > div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs@11.9.1/lib/browser/math.js"></script>
```

## React under observation

### Method

The above test treated the test cases as a black box, measuring duration from the outside. We can also write something to look inside. I'm using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to observe changes to the list's subtree. Every time the <kbd>unshift</kbd> button is pressed, a mutation occurs to the list and there'll be a log showing how many elements changed.

### Results

On every <kbd>unshift</kbd> press:

- `unstable-key` logs `n + 1` elements changed where `n` is the length of the list.
- `stable-key` logs `1` elements changed.

This is expected, given what we know about how React uses keys to determine which elements change ([reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children)).

### Demo

```js
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;

const Test = ({ name }) => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState(Array.from({length: 10000}).map((_, index) => index));
  const targetRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      console.log(`${name} elements updated: ${mutations.length}`);
    });

    observer.observe(
      targetRef.current,
      {
        characterData: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
      }
    );

    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setArr([arr[0] - 1, ...arr])}>unshift</button> 
      <ul ref={targetRef}>
        {arr.map((k, i) => (
          <li key={name === "unstable-key" ? i : k}>{k}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => (
  <div id="wrapper">
    <Test name="unstable-key" />
    <Test name="stable-key" />
  </div>
);

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#wrapper > div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

## So what's happening in your test?

I'm not certain but I suspect it's your browser or machine's performance. Your GIF for the stable keys test showed multiple clicks but there was significant lag in the button's press state at the same time as the lag in displaying DOM updates. I doubt React by itself would cause that. The only way I could reproduce your issue was interacting with your Code Sandbox in a remote virtual machine, where there would be lag between my inputs and the VM's outputs because things have to travel across a network.

Answer (score 0):

Using values as keys (key={i}), React can easily recognize which element has been added or moved, as the indices will change when new elements are inserted at the beginning of the array. This makes the reconciliation process more efficient, as React can quickly identify the differences.

On the other hand, using indices  as keys (key={k}), React needs to compare each value with the previous virtual element to determine if it has been added, removed, or moved. This process could take more time, as it requires a more detailed comparison to establish the differences.